# Reconsider historical lock on "How many monitors do you use? Why? How they are used?"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, locked-question

The post https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2757/40980 has the question body of:

> Why more or less monitors is worse than your configuration?
>
> Why is important use it in this way (position)?
>
> Productivity is obvious, but what specific advantage?
>
> A picture would be nice.

This question is an out right poll.

Unfortunately, it is made worse by the accepted answer having an image shack image that has since been deleted.

> [image]

There really is nothing redeeming of the poll. Most of the images are people showing off their monitors or bragging about the specifications of them circa 2010.

I *was* going to edit out the image shack image (and the 'my current configuration' bit preceding it) on the accepted answer, but its locked and... well... it really isn't a good question.

Comment: Wow. I was thinking of a multithreading synchronization construct... I couldn't figure out how the number might be adjustable! This is why I call a video monitor a **"screen"**.

Comment: @nocomprende that's part of why we went through and cleaned up the [tag:monitor] tag a bit ago (it was ambiguous and so everything appropriate to monitoring was retagged). You can see some of that activity in the [revision history](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/2757/revisions) where we needed a mod to edit the question.

Comment: I don't see a Tag for Monitor or Screen. If we are trying to stop people using Monitor improperly, or start using Screen properly, maybe they should be there, **with a description**?

Comment: @nocomprende The fate of the monitors is described in [Structured Tag Cleanup Initiative Phase II](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7321/40980) - its all different terms that are unambiguously their topics, though it appears that all the computer screen ones got deleted and the other ones weren't about monitors or monitoring at all.

Comment: Thank you. My point is that this issue recurs on all the sites: delete a misused tag, and... it comes back. It would be better to leave the tag there with a proper description, so that people do not misuse it again. (Nobody seems to agree with me on this though.) ESP does not work, you need words to describe what a tag is properly for. Especially if it is one that is commonly misunderstood and revived. On a Programming site, "monitor" refers to a synchronization construct. (It just DOES, OK?)

Comment: @nocomprende it takes a minimum threshold of reputation to re-create the tag.  If it keeps coming back, it can get black listed (as mentioned in the STCI post). Furthermore, with the lower volume we have here, we can see if it gets recreated rather easily, and the 10k stats page has a 'new tags' section in which all the new tags for the past N days are shown (backend, abstract-factory, service-locator, promises, callbacks are some of the recent ones) that again, people do, well, monitor. If it shows up again, it will be handled accordingly. That said, *this* question needs to go.

Comment: And this is always the reply I get. Why don't people see the logic of creating a valid, useful tag with a real description, but instead try to stamp it out over and over? People can't see "nothing", but they can see an existing Tag with a proper description, even if it is not currently used. Then when someone tries to use it improperly, the solution is clear. What is wrong with this concept that no one will accept it? This is a database design issue, someone should agree with me.

Comment: @nocomprende if you have a question about the existence of the monitor tag at this point, I would encourage you to ask it in another question here on meta.  That said, ***this*** question about multiple monitors and how to set them up on your computer, do you have an answer for if it should stay or go?

Answer (score 6):

As someone who answered this question in 2011, I agree with you on both points:

- In its current form, it shouldn't exist: it's a poll and most answers are less than constructive.
- The lock makes it impossible to improve both the question and the answer. A year ago, I was writing [a very detailed article on three vs. two monitors setup](http://blog.pelicandd.com/article/48/), and recalled that I already posted a related answer on Stack Exchange. After finding the answer with the intention of making it more constructive, it appeared that there is nothing I can do because of the lock.

I would suggest to either:

- Remove the question altogether,

or:

1. Unlock the question and edit it in order to be less a poll and more about which setup is actually **objectively** better in specific situations. It's not about “Look at my great setup”, but “If your activity as a developer involves this or that, you can increase your productivity by modifying your setup this way”. This also involves modifying some answers.
2. Cleanup the answers by removing the ones which are nonconstructive.

<sup>Of course, one may notice that I have a personal interest in the second option, which would mean that the top high voted answers will be removed, and mine will become the top one.</sup>

Comment: Very good article (on your blog).

Comment: I will monitor the results closely.

Answer (score 5):

I think the question should be deleted for the reasons stated in this meta question: it is simply not a good question and brings no value to the site.